# Creating class objects from file contents

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to read from a file that has as 3 descriptors per employee that are separated by tabs (first name, last name & pay). Then create employee objects from what I read in the file, but I'm way off of the mark here, can anyone assist? I've tried with and without context managers, different file types (csv and txt), and I still can't create objects from this. PS: in this same file I have a premade employee class that has the same parameters, will include in code.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, bonus=0):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"
        self.bonus = bonus

    def get_pay(self):
        return self.pay

    def set_pay(self, pay1):
        self.pay = pay1

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def get_bonus(self):
        return self.bonus

    def set_bonus(self, bonus):
        self.bonus = bonus


def main():
    employees = []
    f = open('dirany.csv').readlines()
    for line in f:
        employee = line.split('\t')
        fname = employee[0]
        lname = employee[1]
        salary = employee[2]

    print(line)
```

Comment: What part of tis code is even attempting to create an Employee object?

Comment: Will upload my previous attempt, sorry. I hit the drawing board again.

Answer (score 1):

You're close; you just need to call `Employee` and put the result in your list.

```
def main():
    employees = []
    with open('dirany.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            employee = line.split('\t')
            fname = employee[0]
            lname = employee[1]
            salary = employee[2]
            employees.append(Employee(fname, lname, salary))
```

As an aside, you don't need the get and set methods you are defining if they literally do nothing except get and set attribute values. Just use the attributes directly.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, bonus=0):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + "@company.com"
        self.bonus = bonus

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    # You might make full_name a property instead of
    # an ordinary method.
    # @property
    # def full_name(self):
    #     return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
```

Comment: You might want to convert `salary` to a number.

Comment: Perhaps; I'll leave it as is, though, as it's not obvious if the OP would want a float or an int.